# vscode always asking to add include path | C project

Tags: c, macos, include, visual-studio-code

I just noticed (maybe it's recent) that every time I type a new line in a .c file on vscode (or even when I clic on a function name), there is the yellow lightbulb that appears and that asks me to add an include path to the settings. But possible includes specified .. I can't get rid of it and it's getting me crazy.

Here is my c_cpp_properties.json :

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": ["/usr/include", 
            "/Users/XXX/XXX/XXX/includes",
             "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include"],
            "browse" : {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders" : false,
                "databaseFilename" : ""
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": ["/usr/include"],
            "browse" : {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders" : true,
                "databaseFilename" : ""
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": ["c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include"],
            "browse" : {
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders" : true,
                "databaseFilename" : ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks !
(btw i'm on macos sierra)

Comment: which path does vs ask you to add to the list of paths?  Why not just add that path and be done with it?  BTW: on linux (probably) should have the path: `/usr/local/include`  and `.` or `./.`

Comment: from another site: "If you installed the OS X command line tools (OS X 10.9) for Xcode 6.2 (Mar 2015), or for Xcode 6.1.1 (Dec 2014) — then you will have /usr/include available to you."  Other searches also indicated that the command line tools need to be installed to have the `/usr/include` directory  AND that the 'developer center' changes how to do that with each new version of the OS.